# print x labels when y equals NA in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, na

How can I get ggplot to print ALL x labels in this R example?

Note that it does not print the x label for x=2, when y equals NA.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble) 

x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(5,NA,10)

data_trunc <- tsibble(x = x, y = y, index = x)

data_na <- fill_gaps(data_trunc, .full = TRUE)

x_lab <- c('1','2','3')

ggplot(data = data_na, aes(ordered(x), y, group=1 ) ) + 
  geom_line(data=data_na[!is.na(data_na$y),], show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:3, labels=x_lab )
```

[image: missing x label 2 when y equals NA]

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to explicitly set the `limits` of the scale:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)

x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(5, NA, 10)

data_trunc <- tsibble(x = x, y = y, index = x)

data_na <- fill_gaps(data_trunc, .full = TRUE)

x_lab <- c("1", "2", "3")

ggplot(data = data_na, aes(ordered(x), y, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(data = data_na[!is.na(data_na$y), ], show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:3, labels = x_lab, limits = ordered(x))
```

[image]